# How to run app separately from email client after opening attachment

Tags: android, android-activity

Currently my application opens custom files sent via email; after processing the files my application is closed and you're returned to the email.

I'm trying to add an option to return to the main menu after file processing, but at this point I don't want my application to be running within the email applications process/context.

Is there any way to completely fork my application?

Comment: Can you post the code where your app terminates itself?

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility to start task with backstack, where you can configure parent activities in stack. You need to use component [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html).

Main article about it http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html